# Scope / this of callback function

Tags: javascript, scope

I understand the scope of a function should be settled when it's defined.

so from my understanding, the scope of `function(toy)` should be the scope of `forEach` , so `this` should really just be `forEach` ? but it turns out to be global scope. can't figure why

```
function Cat(name) {
  this.name = name;
  this.toys = ['string', 'ball', 'balloon'];
};

Cat.prototype.play = function meow() {
  this.toys.forEach(function(toy) {
    console.log(this);
  });
};

const garfield = new Cat('garfield');
garfield.play();
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As pointed out by others, a function declared using the `function` keyword will have its own `this`, and depends on how the function is called, rather than the context that its defined in. Since you are using `.forEach()` (and seem to be leaning towards es5 syntax), one possible way to change the `this` inside the `forEach()` method is to use the [*thisArg*](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach#Parameters), where you can explicitly state what `this` should be inside your callback function:

```js
function Cat(name) {
  this.name = name;
  this.toys = ['string', 'ball', 'balloon'];
};

Cat.prototype.play = function meow() {
  this.toys.forEach(function(toy) {
    console.log(this);
  }, this);
  //  ^--- specify the thisArg
};

const garfield = new Cat('garfield');
garfield.play();
```

Answer (score 1):

When you declare a function() using ES5 syntax, it has no awareness of lexical scope, thus `this` is bound to the default window.

It's exactly the same as if you declared a named global function and then passed it in by reference. The only difference is that you declared the code inline.

Functions declared on the .prototype chain get auto-bound to their parent object.

If you use the new ES6 syntax `() => {}` then `this` will get bound to the current lexical scope.